# Do you think I should use a comma before not submitted? Predicate ellipsis?

Tags: punctuation

In this text:

> " ... then the file is considered unworkable and must be unclaimed not submitted."

Do you think I should use a comma before *not submitted*?

Comment: Either a comma or some words.  But the sentence doesn't make much sense regardless.